# Chrome CPU profile not storing sourcemaps details?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps, javascript-debugger

I am using chrome's Javascript Profile to store the cpuprofile's. When we capture a cpu profile in chrome, it reads details of source map and shows the path & line number of the actual source file, similar to as shown below.

[image]

However, if I save the profile and load it again, it does not use the source map anymore, as shown below.

[image]

Looks like generated .cpuprofile file does not have any sourcemap related info. I need to get the sourcemap utilized along with the cpuprofile. Is there any way to get this done??